# Is it possible to create a widget version of the Ghostery (or similar) browser extension?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, widget, firefox-addon

I am looking for a way to create a widget version of Ghostery or Disconnect browser extensions. Is it possible for this to live within a website, allowing a user to enter a URL and view third party trackers?

Comment: Based from this [documentation/tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_build_custom_form_widgets), if you go the "Why isn't it working?" part, it says here that "The script is in conflict with, or is affected by, a browser extension (such as Firefox's NoScript extension or Chrome's NotScripts extension)." So I'm not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your proposed idea is as follows:

- Get an URL
- "Load" the page (without actually opening it in the browser)
- Collect the same information as Ghostery does
- Present that to user

The problem comes with "loading" the page without actually loading it by user's browser. You need to fully emulate what the browser does (loading and executing JS, for instance) to collect the same tracking as would happen in a real browser.

It's technically possible, but must be done server-side with something like PhantomJS. It's highly unlikely to work client-side in the browser.